# Change a SQL Server table to use GUID for the primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StatusId]     INT              NOT NULL,
    [Text]         NVARCHAR (400)  NULL,
    [TestUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Test_TestUId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Test]([TestUId] ASC);
```

How can I change this to use GUID as the primary key and have an index on TestId ?

Comment: perhaps  make some kind of attempt....??

Comment: Why do you want to use a GUID primary key here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just alter the table and make the TestUId as Primary Key. If you want to define Clustered Index for primary key, then remove the existing clustered index.

```
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TestUId)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to explicitly name constraints to facilitate subsequent table changes.  I suggest you use NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID() since incremental keys will improve performance with large tables.  Below is an example, assuming you want a clustered primary key index.

```
DECLARE 
    @ConstraintName sysname
    ,@SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @ConstraintName = name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Test')
AND type = 'PK';
SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
    DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@ConstraintName) + ';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TestUId);
DROP INDEX dbo.Test.index_TestId;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_TestId ON Test (TestId);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can establish the primary key at the table creation, and add the additional index afterwards.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Text]  NVARCHAR (400) NULL,
    [TestUId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([TestUId])
)
CREATE INDEX index_TestId ON Test (TestId)
```